# Storing TIMESTAMP field in MySQL as datetime in SQL Server using Ruby

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, sql-server, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Im writing a job in my Rails application to migrate some data from a MySQL database to Microsoft SQL Server. In my orders table in MySQL the billing_date field is a TIMESTAMP, whereas the same field in SQL Server is of type datetime.
I have the following code:

```
def order_columns
  %w{INVOICE_NUMBER BILLING_DATE}
end

invoice_number = @order.invoice_number
billing_date   = @order.billing_date
values = [invoice_number, billing_date]
@query += "INSERT INTO ORDER (%s) VALUES (%s);" % [order_columns.join(","),values.join(",")]
```

The billing_date value in MySQL is `2016-09-02 08:43:10` . When the query gets executed i get the following error `Incorrect syntax near '08'`.

Is the query formulation correct ? If yes, what is the correct way of storing the billing_date of type TIMESTAMP to a datetime field in SQL Server ?

Comment: When you execute an db insert statement like that then really there is nothing Rails can do about it! Rails, in your case ActiveRecord can only write proper date if you use it in the way it wants you to... not when you use an insert statement like that. Can you add more to your question, probably more about the `Order` model? There should be a way to come up with a desired solution!

Comment: Sorry for confusion. We have models for the tables in MySQL but not for the tables in the SQL Server database. We are using https://github.com/rails-sqlserver/tiny_tds to interface with SQL Server using raw sql queries.

Comment: Well if you're really after executing the query as such surround your values with quotes, as: `INSERT INTO ORDER '(%s)' VALUES '(%s)';...`